# java tries to update every day

Tags: windows-7, java

I am running java on a win7 environment. The issue is that it asks for update every day but does not find any updates. Shouldn't it find out when is it that there exists something new to update to, and only then initialize and update?

Comment: On my system, it keeps finding the same update over and over again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not clear. (Are you looking for the reason of No New Updates or Wants to get rid of that popup)

If you just want to get rid of the dialog box asking for **Java Update** everyday, you can do it like this:

- Go to **Control Panel** and type `java` in search box.
- Select the java control panel.
- In `Update` tab, you can schedule how often to check for updates, as well as have the option to     update manually at any time.
  .

  - Set `Notify Me` to `Before Installing`
  - Click `Advanced..` and set update frequency to `weekely` or `monthly`.

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

What version of Java do you currently have installed?  You can follow the same directions that Lamb gave above to get to the Java Control Panel and then choose the Java tab and view to see what version you have installed.  The current version is 1.7.0_55, if you do not have that version you may want to go to http://java.com and download the most recent version, possibly something is preventing the Java program from doing the update even though it is detecting the update is available.  Often there are multiple versions installed, unless you need an older version remove all but the most recent version of Java.